# Each sub_id with latest date and status select?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

[image]

```
Select p_id,max(dates)--,status,sub_id
from table_name
group by p_id;
```

**incase i have use group by clause based on p_id, then how to return status and sub_id**

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this

```
select p_id, status , sub_id from table1  t 
    inner join (Select p_id,max(dates) 
          from table1  group by p_id) g
     on t.p_id= g.p_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Make inline view with max(dates) and join with same table to get all the required column as below.

```
**Create table:**
CREATE TABLE table_name(ID NUMBER,p_id VARCHAR2(10),sub_id 
VARCHAR2(10),status VARCHAR2(10),dates DATE); 

**SQL Query:**
SELECT T.P_ID, SUB_ID, STATUS, INLINE_VIEW.DATES
 FROM TABLE_NAME T,
   (SELECT P_ID, MAX(DATES) DATES FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY P_ID) INLINE_VIEW
 WHERE T.P_ID = INLINE_VIEW.P_ID
 AND T.DATES = INLINE_VIEW.DATES
 ORDER BY T.P_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about this but here is one straight forward approach.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P_ID ORDER BY DATES DESC) AS rn,
        T.P_ID, SUB_ID, STATUS, INLINE_VIEW.DATES
    FROM TABLE_NAME AS T
) AS u
WHERE u.rn = 1
```